# Query azure application gateway settings or whole ARM template from azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-api-management

Hello I want to build back end c# where i will able to query all settings of the azure application gateway i have already configured. I have tried with Frontdoor and used Frontdoorclient to connect to frontdoor and able to query all loadbalancer settings and other settings. That helped me because front door on Azure.management.Fluent.Frontdoor.dlll has client and for azure.mamgement.network.dll i cant find client for azure application gateway.

Comment: Please refer to the sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/application-gateway-dotnet-manage-simple-application-gateways/getting-started-on-managing-simple-application-gateways-in-c/

Comment: Hi burim Any update?

Comment: I need client accesaing a0plication gateway like FeintdoorManagementClient it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SDK does not provide a management client to directly manage Azure application gateway. If we want to manage it, we should use `NetworkManagementClient.ApplicationGateways` to manage it. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.network.networkmanagementclient?view=azure-dotnet#properties)

1. Create a service principal and assign a role to sp

```
az login
az account set --subscription "<your subscription id>"
# the sp will have Azure Contributor role
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "readMetric"
```

[image]

2. Code

```
# use msal get token
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(<sp app id>)
           .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "<sp tenantID>")
           .WithClientSecret(<sp password>)
           .Build();
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" };
var  result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                   .ExecuteAsync();
TokenCredentials tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken,"Bearer");

 NetworkManagementClient networkManagementClient = new NetworkManagementClient(tokenCredentials);
ApplicationGateway appgateway =await networkManagementClient.ApplicationGateways.GetAsync("<groupName>", "<resourceName>");

// get application gateway settings:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.network.models.applicationgateway?view=azure-dotnet
```

Comment: How can implement this by that what you have written ,  ` this.credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(this.cpSettings.AccessKey, this.cpSettings.AccessSecret, this.cpSettings.TenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);  var fdCredentials = this.credentials.WithDefaultSubscription(this.cpSettings.SubscriptionId);

           var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
               .Configure()
               .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
               .Authenticate(fdCredentials).WithDefaultSubscription(); `

Comment: and then   var clientList = azure.ApplicationGateways.ListAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult().ToList(); can i do this way ?

Comment: @burim yes you can do the way.